# Problem with gnu radio on raspberry pi 4. Can't create python code

Tags: raspberry-pi4, gnuradio

I followed these instructions to build and install gnuradio on my raspberry pi 4.  Everything went well and all tests pasts.

However when I connect blocks together and try to run them,  the conversion from grc to python fails.   Even for simple examples the python file does not get written.  This is what gets written to the console (see below).   Any help would be appreciated.

```
Loading: "/home/pi/src/tutorial3.grc"
>>> Done
Warning: restarting the docstring loader (crashed while loading 'uhd_amsg_source')
Warning: restarting the docstring loader
Warning: restarting the docstring loader
Warning: restarting the docstring loader
Warning: restarting the docstring loader
Warning: docstring loader crashed too often

Generating: '/home/pi/src/tutorial3.py'
Generate Error: (NameError("'no_quotes' is not defined"), '<%\n    win = \'self._%s_win\'%id\n    range = \'self._%s_range\'%id\n%>\\\n${range} = Range(${start}, ${stop}, ${step}, ${value}, ${min_len})\n${win} = RangeWidget(${range}, self.set_${id}, "${no_quotes(label,repr(id))}", "${widget}", ${rangeType}, ${orient})\n${gui_hint() % win}')
>>> Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "memory:0x9a5734d0", line 64, in render_body
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 101, in __getitem__
    return compat_builtins.__dict__[key]
KeyError: 'no_quotes'
```

Comment: "I followed these instructions to build and install": *which* instructions?

Comment: Here is the link to the instructions I followed to build and install gnuradio on raspberrypi:   https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR#From_Source

Comment: Um, you really shouldn't be building GNU Radio on a raspberry Pi. If you just use the current Raspberry Pi Os (released end of october), then you can `apt install gnuradio gnuradio-dev` and get GNU Radio 3.8.2, which is recent enough! What's the version of GNU Radio you've built? This error is peculiar!

Comment: Thanks for the comment.    However, when I do this the version of gnuradio-companion is GNU Radio Companion 3.7.13.4.    That is not compatible with the grc file I am trying to use.

Comment: yes, as said you need the current version of Raspberry Pi OS, not an older one, and not Raspbian.

Comment: That worked.   Thanks so much!